# Got Error: "Specified block size is not valid for this algorithm" while initialize AesCryptoProvider

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I am trying to use larger block size for the AES Encryption:

```
private static void EncryptFile(string inFile, RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaPublicKey)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        // Create instance of AesManaged for
        // symetric encryption of the data.
        aes.KeySize = 256;

        // Allocating 64K
        aes.BlockSize = 8 * 1024 * 64; 
    }
}
```

and hitting the following exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was unhandled
>   Message=Specified block size is not valid for this algorithm.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm.set_BlockSize(Int32
>   value)
>          at ConsoleApplication4.Program.EncryptFile(String inFile, RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaPublicKey) in
>   C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs:line 117

I sure am missing somehting ovbious, any clue?

Comment: Did you look it up in [LegalBlockSizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks! Myself or .NET - either one of us is dumb. If BlockSize is fixed (which it seem to be), then why is it a mutable property?

Comment: It is a property of the base class [SymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx), which is very generic. Some algorithms support multiple block sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that AES only supports block size equal to 128.  It appears that you can get around this by processing your data as multiple blocks.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Only certain block sizes are supported by each algorithm.

See [`SymmetricAlgorithm.LegalBlockSizes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes.aspx).